# Flash player dosen't work in Opera

Tags: video, flash, opera

I have been using Opera for several months, but a few days the flash player stop working. I have tried installing using sudo apt install adobe-flashplugin, but its already install.

Maybe someone have the same problem and maybe know how can I resolve this problem?

('m using Opera Developer Versión:61.0.3271.0 and Ubuntu Mate 18.04. Previusly I was using Opera Version 61 (not developer), but since few months ago it stop working and now I have the same problem with this Opera.)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that its allowed?

Settings --> Advanced --> Privacy & Security --> Content Settings and check "Allow sites to run Flash" to be ON

Also, if you share more info about your current OS, browser version etc ...
you will have better chances someone to help you.

gl

Comment: I dont found that option D: . I use the search for word "Flash" and there is no result.
I'm using Opera Developer Versión:61.0.3271.0 and Ubuntu Mate 18.04. Previusly I was using Opera Version 61 (not developer), but since few months ago it stop working and now I have the same problem with this Opera.